# Access forbidden in /web directory Symfony2 project

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, symfony-2.3

I'm working on a Symfony2 project at local server without any virtual hosting or something else. After I run the command `php app/console assets:install --symlink`, clear the cache and refresh the page none styles or javascript or images are loaded. Inspecting the source code and trying to access any of those assets I get this error:

> You don't have permission to access
>   /cmplatform/web/bundles/clanmovilcommon/css/bootstrap.min.css on this
>   server.

What I need to change in my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` to fix that problem? It's related to `.htaccess` problem or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is due to the user that you are currently logged in as not having correct to write to the /cmplatform/web directory. Or you have not got the root path set correctly in your apache.conf.

Can you confirm other pages / assets are being served correctly.

Take a look at who owns the directory and either adjust the write permissions or add your user / web server to own the directory or into the group.

This is quite a common issue - and care needs to be taken to ensure that write permissions for web, cache and log directories are set correctly to allow command line and web server (e.g. apache / nginx) users.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html - permissions for some tips about fixing this.

Comment: In my case, error log was useful: "Permiso denegado: access to /test.php denied (filesystem path '/home/myuser/myweb') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path".